# Error running Rails server on OS 10.10.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

### Versions

Mac OS: OSX 10.10.2
Ruby: 2.2.1p85
Rails: 4.2.0

### Context

I am following the "Install Rails" tutorial online at www.installrails.com. Finally made it through after encountering many errors. I am on the last step of creating a sample app, which it worked fine, and then running the server. Now, I run into another error.

### Errors

Here is what I am seeing:

```
/Users/Work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000418
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------

See Crash Report log file under the one of following:

     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------

*A lot of information listed here*

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------

*A lot of information listed here*

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------

*A lot of information listed here*

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------


*A lot of information listed here*

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: bin/rails

* Loaded features:

*And then a long list of files listed here*

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

### Help

Now, I am wondering if it is the json gem that is causing a problem?

Let me know if you need any of the removed information. The bug report was really long so I removed the codes where it says *A lot of information listed here* for brevity.

Comment: Try to remove all `2.2.1` ruby versions from `rvm` and install one latest again.

Comment: I got exactly same problem :<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per a suggestion by @maxd, I ended up having to uninstall and reinstall ruby.

Here is the process I followed.

1. I uninstalled Ruby with command line `rvm remove 2.2.1`
2. I reinstall 2.2.1 with the command line `rvm install 2.2.1`
3. Then I reinstalled rails with command line `sudo gem install rails`
4. Then I used `bundle install` to reinstall missing gems
5. Next, I used `gem install rubygems-update` to update Rubygems from 2.0.14 to 2.1.
6. Then I reset gems to pristine condition with `gem pristine --all`.
7. Then for some reason I had to rerun `bundle install` because actionmailer 4.2.0 was no longer showing as being installed, even though it was in the list after the first `bundle install`.
8. Finally running `rails -v` gave me an output of `Rails 4.2.0` instead of error codes.

So, I ran `rails server` and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. But I not certain this is a GOOD way.

first, I reinstalled ruby. since, I looks like version problem as I see.

`rvm reinstall all`

and `gem install rails`. After this process, I can run server with `rails server` command.

I hope this could be a your solution too. Have a good day :D

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem in my mac mini(M1). The following solution worked for me found in [the developer forum.](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652822)

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

Then

arch -x86_64 pod install
```